# Appium is able to see beyond what is displayed on screen

Tags: java, appium

Appium is able to see and find elements that is not displayed on screen

I am trying to build a test automation project, I would like my driver to scroll down 
 and then perform some operation. but for some reason appium is able to find element even without scrolling down . I am not sure how appium is able to identify element that is not on screen and is only visible to naked eye when you scroll down. Anyone with similar issue found a workaround ?

I am using ExpectedCondition.visibilityOF(element) to determine if element is vsible on screen

```
  public boolean verifyCoverage(String coverage, String value, String type) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        AndroidElement element = (AndroidElement) driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("UiSelector().textContains(\"" + coverage + "\")");
        //WebElement coverageOption= driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[contains(text(),'"+coverage+"')]");
        if (AndroidUtilities.waitForVisibility(driver, element)) {

            return true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println ("Cannot see");

            return false;
        }

    }

public static boolean waitForVisibility(AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver, AndroidElement AndroidElement){
    try{
        // driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("UiSelector().resourceId(\""+targetResourceId+"\")");

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(AndroidElement));
        boolean isElementPresent = AndroidElement.isDisplayed();
        return isElementPresent;    
    }catch(Exception e){
        boolean isElementPresent = false;
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return isElementPresent;
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess you are working with iOS device, am i right?

Comment: No I am using android .  I have a function wherein  when it is not visible : expectedCondition.VisibilityOf(element) it should return false , it should scroll down and then look for it again . but right now appium is able to find element even without scrolling down and clicks the last element that it can see on screen (ideally it is trying to click on the element that we cant see)

Comment: Could you please provide your code to clarify what you are actually doing

Comment: added code in the main question

Comment: @Vault23 any luck

Comment: I am not near my pc now, firstly try to use visibilityOfElementLocated instead of visibilityOf

Comment: You could also try waiting on `elementToBeClickable` instead of `visibilityOf`. This may return more accurate results.

Comment: Hi Christine, thanks for you reply but unfortunately this method still doesn't work ;

Answer (score 0):

As an answer i would recommend you to use `visibilityOfElementLocated` instean of `visibilityOf`.
Plus, if you want to check an element for the existence without getting exceptions, try to take that approach:

```
if (!((AndroidDriver)driver).findElementsByAndroidUIAutomator("UiSelector().textContains(\"" + coverage + "\")").isEmpty()) {
 //some logic when element is located
} else {
 //scroll to the particular element
}
```

Comment: I tried but it is not helping. it is still returning count as non empty and able to find element

Answer (score 0):

You can try these two solution within the page it will able to scroll to the element and do your actions .

```
MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\""+element+"\").instance(0))"));


 MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textMatches(\"" + NumbersCount + "\").instance(0))"));
```